# how to customize html element using blaze

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

A simple example so you can understand me:

### I have a template called button:

```
<template name="button">
   <button>
      //some content
   </button>
</template>
```

---

then when i click it how to customize it using JS

```
Template.button.events({
   'click': function (e, t) {
      var b = e.currentTarget;
      // what i must do here ?
   }
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by "customize"? css? behavior when you click on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Template.button.events({
  'click button': function (e, t) {
    let b = e.target
    b.style.width="100px"
}
})
```

Comment: that's what am looking for but why b.elementType return undefined ?

Comment: what do you mean by b.elementType??

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish but I would do something like this.

main.css

```
.blue-bg{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

main.html

```
<template name="button">
    <button data-my-button class={{bgColor}}>
        Click Me!
    </button>
</template>
```

main.js

```
Template.button.onCreated(function () {
    var instance = this;
    //default to no color
    instance.color = new ReactiveVar('');
});

Template.button.helpers({
    bgColor: function () {
        var instance = Template.instance();
        return instance.color.get();
    }
});

Template.button.events({
    'click [data-my-button]': function (event, instance) {
        instance.color.set('blue-bg');
    }
});
```